# Update Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

How to i update a certain value in the database?

```
class Userdata(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Fakultas,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default= 1)
    is_voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):return self.user.username

class Voting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Fakultas, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    pic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    voters = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self): return self.name
```

My Views :

```
def voted(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        id = response.POST.get['idcalon']
        user = Userdata.objects.get() #get the username
        calon2 = Voting.objects.get() #get user selection in html
        user.is_voted = True
        calon2.voters +=1
        user.save(['is_voted'])
        calon2.save(['voters'])
```

I'm trying to grab the user's name and then when update  the user's is_voted value to True when triggered.

Then, I wanted to grab my Voting model by id, for example, I wanted to edit id = 1

So how do I do it? I've been trying to understand the documentation, but still have 0 idea how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def voted(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST.get['idcalon']
        user = Userdata.objects.get(id=request.user.id) #get the username
        calon2 = Voting.objects.get(id=id) #get user selection in html
        user.is_voted = True
        calon2.voters +=1
        user.save()
        calon2.save()
```

this will work if user is authenticated